self-signed certificate doesnt work in my browser firefox/chrome
Self-signed certificate is generated by openssl utility.
CA.crt and intermediate.crt are added to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ and  /usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/anchors/ on my client host(Fedora)
I do #sudo update-ca-trust
Server side (nginx) certs are added
curl works
tuy@tuy:~$ curl https://www-1.example.com
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>


tuy@tuy:~$ firefox https://www-1.example.com

Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead

Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to https://www-1.example.com. If you visit this site, attackers could try to steal information like your passwords, emails, or credit card details.

In browser certificate autority list my CA and intermediate exist
WTF?

Please provide the actual certificate. Please also provide the detailed error message from the browser (see "Advanced" in the error page).
